# Laravel 5.3: UnitTest on API - multiple function lead to error

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, phpunit

Hope someone can help me out here. I bootstrapped a Laravel 5.3 application and I'm writing JUnitTest in order to verifiy my API.

However, as long as I create only one function in the Test Class everything works fine:

```
class MobileAppTest extends TestCase {

function __construct()
{
    parent::setUp();
}

public function testUserLogin()
{
    $this->json('POST', '/mobile/auth', ['username' => 'empty', 'password' => 'demo'])
        ->seeJson([
            'success' => true
        ]);

    $this->json('POST', '/mobile/auth', ['username' => 'wrongUser', 'password' => 'demo'])
        ->seeJson([
            'success' => false,
            'state' => 2
        ]);
}}
```

When I start to add another function like this:

```
class MobileAppTest extends TestCase{

function __construct()
{
    parent::setUp();
}

public function testUserLogin()
{
    $this->json('POST', '/mobile/auth', ['username' => 'empty', 'password' => 'demo'])
        ->seeJson([
            'success' => true
        ]);

    $this->json('POST', '/mobile/auth', ['username' => 'wrongUser', 'password' => 'demo'])
        ->seeJson([
            'success' => false,
            'state' => 2
        ]);
}

public function testSecond()
{

}}
```

Suddenly the parameters of the HTTP POST call become empty. I have no idea why this is happening. On the server-log there is the following message poping up:

```
[2017-05-10 11:09:15] testing.INFO: array (
)  
[2017-05-10 11:09:15] testing.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined index: username 
in app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php:36
```

But on the second call the parameters are present:

```
[2017-05-10 11:09:15] testing.INFO: array (
'username' => 'wrongUser',
'password' => 'demo',
)
```

Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: Why you use __construct? Did not parent automatically setting up?
Try to separate second request to testSecond() and do not leave empty test function

Comment: Also if I separate the second request to testSecond (so I have in total only two requests, one per function). I get the following error:          MobileAppTest::testUserLogin
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:114) This seems to me, that there is something totally wrong here...?!

Comment: Maybe add to your phpunit.xml <phpunit processIsolation="true"

Comment: Looks like setting <phpunit processIsolation="true" in phpunit.xml fixed the problem. Thx!